# How to say "My biggest (Something I am attracted to)"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

So if I want to say "Red hair is one of my biggest [insert word here]", meaning that it is one of the things I am most attracted to, is there a word I could use to complete the sentence?

Comment: "Weakness" is a possible term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Turn-on" is probably the best word to fit there. Here's the [definition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turn+on)

> To be or cause to become interested, pleasurably excited, or stimulated. Or to excite or become excited sexually.

["Attraction"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/attraction) is another one:

> the action or power of evoking interest, pleasure, or liking for someone or something

Comment: I thought so, but I was trying to avoid using that. I was looking to use it in a more friendly manner. Thank you though :)

Comment: You could also simply use "attraction". I think that works as well.

Comment: Oh, you're right! :) I didn't know it could be used in that way haha thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to include that :)

Comment: I don't think "Red hair is one of my biggest attractions" works. It means you're the one with the red hair and others are attracted to it.

Comment: RE: _I thought so, but I was trying to avoid using that._ I don't understand why pertinent information like that is left out of so many questions. If you had already thought of _turn-on_, and you were looking for a less suggestive alternative, then why didn't you say that in your quesiton? SE questions are not like tweets; there is no need to conserve characters.

Answer (score 0):

You've left a comment underneath an answer here that provides a critical piece of information: You're looking for an alternative to *turn-on*, which isn't sufficiently neutral.

That being the case, I'm not sure a noun is what you want. I just checked a thesaurus, which offered:

> attraction, aphrodisiac, thrill, stimulant, rush, inducement

and I don't think any of those fit very well. However, if you get away from the "one of my 
biggest `<noun>`" construct, there are other ways to express the same sentiment, such as:

> ***Red hair really catches my eye***.

or even:

> ***I really appreciate a mane of red hair.***

Answer (score 0):

Although the word **"fetish"** has several meanings, (from a magical object, to a sexual obsession/perversion) it would be appropriate in your example:

"Red hair is one of my biggest ***fetishes***."